# null value is getting passed when using Parse JSON

Tags: power-automate

In Power Automate I am using Json to read excel table and transfer in sharepoint list, Json works fine, even if I check values in compose it shows all column values however when I put apply each for create sharepoint item certain colmns are getting null value

Details as per below

**Json output **

```
{
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "8f0d3d4b-59d2-4655-ba7c-91661df09a6c",
  "Improvement Area": "Workshop & Technician",
  "Area of Action": "Final 1-Test1- Area of action",
  "Agreed Action \n( Action that can be tracked)": "Final 1-Test1- Agreed Action",
  "Action owner\n(Name) ": "Final 1-Test1- Action owner",
  "Column1": "",
  "Planned closure date\n(MM/DD/YYYY)": "45297"
}
```

Create item input

Here AgreedAction_x0028_Actionthatcan, Actionowner, Plannedclosuredate are getting null value whereas Json out put has these values
Could you please help me out in this

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "PostItem"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": https://versuni.sharepoint.com/sites/IndiaCEO,
        "table": "e8084831-db40-4159-931b-2f0c6bb85881",
        "item/Title": "Workshop & Technician",
        "item/ImprovementArea": "Workshop & Technician",
        "item/AreaofAction": "Final 1-Test1- Area of action",
        "item/AgreedAction_x0028_Actionthatcan": null,
        "item/Actionowner": null,
        "item/Plannedclosuredate": null
    }
}
```

I tried with changing list, and excel but still it is not working

Comment: Ask yourself this ... could you help 100% with what you've given us to work with?  You've left out the most important part, show us the flow.  Also, you have column names in Excel with line breaks?  I'd start there.